# Why doesn't Drizzt change his last name?

Tags: forgotten-realms, legend-of-drizzt

Drizzt Do'Urden escaped the drow city of Menoberzzeran and ran away to the surface world, where he met Breunor, Regis, Catti-Brie, and Wulfgar. Since he hates evil (his stat block says he is Chaotic Good), why doesn't he change his surname to something other than a drow house? In the prelude trilogy, it is clear that House Do'Urden rejected him as a rogue, so why does he keep his surname?

Comment: A name is just a name.  Associating a family name with the deeds of that family (and thus wanting to distance oneself from those deeds by changing one's name) seems like a Lawful thing to do.

Comment: I always had the impression he knew he would face hostility outside drow society no matter what he called himself; to most surface dwellers (and many Underdark dwellers) a drow is a drow no matter what house he came from, so changing it wouldn't really change anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Drizzt leaves Menoberzzeran, House Do'Urden is effectively no more. With him being the last remaining noble of the house, there is no reason for him to change it any more because he can make the name associated with good instead of evil.

Comment: He didn't know that until The Legacy.

Answer (score -1):

For a more Doylist response, because it's faintly alliterative.

Comment: This would make a passable answer if you could identify that this was what the author had in mind. We tend to shy away from out-of-universe answers otherwise.